# Symfony2 and assets on shared hosting

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, symfony, shared-hosting

Im developing with the symfony2 framework and i'm trying to find the best solution for the next problem.

I have a localhost configured with a WAMP installation. Where the document_root is the /web/ directory. In the web/css/main.css file im using images with a static path to "/images/header.png" and such.

Now on my hosting provider i only have access to write to the /www/ folder and i was forced to put all the project files to this document_root. All the requests are now redirected with a .htaccess file with "RewriteBase /web/". Now my assets didnt load properly. And i needed to changed the paths to /web/images/header.png" in the css files.

With this issue. My dev and prod environment are not the same anymore.

What would be a great solution. And is there a best practise for this?

Comment: get a proper host, digital ocean and similar will put you back $5 for a vps where you control everything yourself

Comment: Thanks Kal! Its the same indeed.